# Why does the matrix product of Jacobian of coordinate transformation and Jacobian of reverse coordinate transformation equals the identity matrix

Tags: matrices, multivariable-calculus

Why does the matrix product of the Jacobian of coordinate transformation (J) and the Jacobian of reverse coordinate transformation (J') equal the identity matrix (I)?

Answer (score 1):

That's a consequence of the chain rule. Note that, if $\phi$ denote the coordinate transform, we have for any $x \in \Omega$ ($\Omega$ the domain in question),
$$ (\phi^{-1} \circ \phi)(x) = x $$
Taking derivatives, this gives 
$$ {\rm Id} = D(\phi^{-1}\circ \phi)(x) = D\phi^{-1}\bigl(\phi(x)\bigr)D\phi(x) $$
Or writing it with the representing matrices: Denote the Jacobian of a function $f$ at $x$ by $J_f(x)$, we have that
$$ J_{\phi^{-1}}\bigl(\phi(x)\bigr) \cdot J_\phi(x) = {\rm Id} $$